# Appengine Python Async urlfetch After Request Ends

Tags: google-app-engine, asynchronous, webapp2, urlfetch

If I make a `urlfetch.make_fetch_call` (from a `webapp2.RequestHandler`) with an RPC that has a callback, and don't wait on the RPC, and the Appengine request finishes, what happens to the async call? Will it terminate, or does Appengine let it complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement from the docs [1] is a hint:

"The callback does not occur in the background; the application must call a method (wait(), check_success() or get_result()) to invoke the callback function."

In general, async calls are still local to the request and don't run in a separate process on the App Engine runtime (ie. they are "user" threads and not "daemon" threads, if you want to look into it further). Once your request terminates (either by DeadlineExceededError or otherwise) any pending async calls will terminate as well.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests

Comment: So it depends on when the `RequestHandler`s process terminates?

Comment: Exactly. A user thread cannot outlive the process which spawned it. The SDK's use of the Python threading module can be seen in the source, but it's a bit hairy - https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api

Comment: I'd love to go digging through that when I have the time. I'm also assuming that production appengine works differently. My main question would be whether each `RequestHandler` runs in its own process (I hope not).